# Use visualvm to find portal bottleneck

Tags: java, performance, portal, visualvm

We have a liferay portal running on our intranet.
Everything works fine except the login. Very slow.
I'm thinking of using visualvm to monitor tomcat thread to see what happen in my webserver (like what hook it's calling or does it make some request to our active directory...)
Can I do it with visualvm? If not is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look to see if you can increase the logging levels as you do the test and see if the logs show anything more specific. If the threads are simply waiting on a response from the active directory I doubt that visualvm will show you anything. One thing it might show you is that the thread is waiting.

Comment: can we see what object the thread is calling or where the thread is waiting? if i find the hook i think i can kill the bottleneck

Comment: you can definitely do it if you were to do a stack dump. I think that you could do this using visualvm, but it's probably worth giving it a try to see.

Answer (score 0):

I'd think about a network traffic monitor, like Fiddler.

Comment: i'm not sure about the active directory thing... but i'll try some network traffic monitor tool. But fiddler only runs on windows, doesn't it? and capture only http(s) traffic?

Comment: What protocol do you think your portal running under Tomcat is using?

Comment: But if it is active directory, he could monitor the LDAP calls (and responses), and then might be able to determine if that was the problem.